# <ul> not working properly in IE9?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, html-lists

Hi I have a bizarre problem. When I open my site http://www.blackflow.pl/ in IE9 "Polecamy" section on the blue footer(bottom part) gets messed up. It works when I turn on the "compability mode". When you look at the source it's just a simple list.

Everything works fine on other browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `<strong>` tag as a direct child of a `<ul>` is invalid HTML.  Infact, if you run your webpage through the w3 validator, you'll see that it has 46 errors, quite a few of which are related to that `<ul>` with a  in it.

Edit: Looks like I saw the wrong ul...  But the one you're having the problems with has the same error.

Comment: problem solved, I've neglected to close 2 links with </a>...but still I can't imagine why it looked like a line break...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

actually this ul isn't the same as the rest - the first "a" element is right under the ul and not inside the first li. this probably what's causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong on "Polcamy":

```
<a class="footer" href="http://blackflow.pl/index.php?id=11" target="_self">
<strong>Polecamy</strong>


<li>-Serwis Komputerowy</li>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may render the page as IE8/IE7 like

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
```